# Android does not create local file

Tags: java, android

Grief with my Android code. I'm really confused why this isn't working. I'm trying to save a Hashmap to local file storage but I can't even get the file to exist.
This method is called right at the start of the program so the file can be used later.

The debug announces 'Not'... then 'Still doesnt'  so I assume its not getting created and I see no no exceptions.
Clearly I'm missing something.

```
   public LighManager(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;


    File file = mContext.getFileStreamPath("RobLights.tmp");
    if (file.exists()){

        Log.d("Fileexists", "indeed");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Fileexists", "Not");
        try {
            file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "RobLights.tmp");
        }catch (Exception x ){

            Log.d(TAG, "Exception " +x.toString());
        }
    }

    if (file.exists()){

        Log.d("Fileexists", "now it dooes");
    }else{

        Log.d("Fileexists", "Still doesnt");

    }
```

The above is called from:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private NetworkHostSocket mHostSocket = null;

public LightingSystem systemclass;
public LighManager mLighManager;


public MyApplication() {
    super();
}
  public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
     mLighManager=new LighManager(this);
     mLighManager.readDataFromFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

The big one is that you think that `new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "RobLights.tmp")` creates a file. It does not. It creates a Java `File` object, representing a location on the filesystem. If you want the file to exist, you need use Java file I/O to write to the location pointed to by that `File`.

Second, you are defining `file` twice, once using the above code snippet, and once using `mContext.getFileStreamPath("RobLights.tmp")`. IIRC, those do actually resolve to the same location. However, to be safe, I suggest only defining `file` once.

Comment: Thanks - I will check this!

Comment: This helped, aside from other problems it's working now